# There exists $P\in \mathbb{R}[X]$ such that : $P(J)^n=I_p+J$?

Tags: matrices

Let $J\in \mathcal{M}_{p}(\mathbb{R})$  defined by:
$$
    J=\left [ \begin{matrix}
    0& 0& 0& \dots &0&0\\
    1& 0& 0&\dots &0&0\\
    0 & 1& 0& \dots &0&0 \\
    \vdots & \vdots& \vdots& \vdots&  \vdots\\
    0 & 0&0&\dots&1&0\\
   \end{matrix} \right ]
$$
Why, for $n\geq 1$, there exists $P\in \mathbb{R}[X]$ such that : $P(J)^n=I_p+J$? Any idea please.

Comment: What is $I_p$? Is it $I_n$?

Comment: I corrected the error, thank you

Comment: So n and p are independent, right?

Comment: @Nightflight, yes

Comment: Let $P(X)=c_pX^p+\cdots+c_1X+c_0$. By comparing coefficients on both sides of $P(J)^n=I+J$ (note that $J^p=0$), one can set up recurrence relations between the coefficients $c_k$s.